# If $x:[0,a]\to \Bbb{R}^n$ is differentiable, what is $\frac{d}{dt}\Vert x(t)\Vert^2?$

Tags: derivatives

Let $\Vert\;\Vert$ be the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$. Let $x:[0,a]\to \Bbb{R}^n$ be differentiable. How do I define
\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\Vert x(t)\Vert^2?\end{align}
Please, I need help on this! A detailed answer would suit me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's $$\frac d{dt}(x_1(t)^2+\cdots+x_n(t)^2).$$

Comment: Observe that $\|x(t)\|^2=\langle  x(t),x(t)\rangle$ where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the scalar product, which is a bilinear map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vector form
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Vert x(t)\Vert^2=\frac{d}{dt}(x\cdot x)=(\dot{x}\cdot x)+(x\cdot \dot{x})=2\dot{x}\cdot x$$

Comment: Please, why did you take one as a vector as the other as a scalar?

Comment: @Mike They're both vectors. $\dot x$ means $\frac{d}{dt} x$. It's a notation especially common in physics.

Comment: Oh! Thanks @Arthur!

Answer (score 2):

If $x(t)=(x_1(t),...,x_n(t))$, then

$f(t)=||x(t)||^2=x_1^2(t)+...+x_n^2(t)$, hence

$f'(t)=2x_1(t)x'_1(t)+...+2x_n(t)x_n'(t)$.